# SASS proper syntax for function that will add selectors to element

Tags: sass

How can I apply to my `#demo` element my `actions` function?
I tried this code but it doesn't work and I cannot find a proper syntax for this.

Function:

```
=actions($element)
    #{element}:hover
        opacity: 0.8

    #{element}:active
        opacity: 0.4
```

Element:

```
#demo
    backgroud: red

    +actions(&)
```

This should compile to something like this:

```
#demo
    background:red

#demo:hover
    opacity: 0.8

#demo:active
    opacity: 0.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mistake you made was during the interpolation, you missed the `$`

You wrote `#{element}:hover` instead of `#{$element}:hover`

This is what your function should look like

```
=actions($element)
  @at-root
    #{$element}:hover
      opacity: 0.8

    #{$element}:active
      opacity: 0.4

#demo
  backgroud: red
  +actions(&)
```

Which compiles to the following css

```
#demo {
  backgroud: red;
}
#demo:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#demo:active {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Without the `@at-root` directive you would end up with css that looks like this

```
#demo #demo:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Well explained. Thank you very much.